# From apify to google sheet: how to import specific colums into a sheet?

Tags: web-crawler, html-parsing, apify

Newcomer in the nocode world, i am discovering Apify which is a nice solution to crawl URL and retreive quite easily specific elements from a webpage. The Web Scraper provided by Apify is very nice and powerful.

Now, I want to make a step further and use a external source to get the url (Google Sheet, Airtable...) and automatize the scraping part.

My question is simple: How to automatically retrive an URL from a external database and paste it directly into the Start URL field as shown below:
[Apify Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Twh.jpg)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You need "Integrations" tab, there you will see available options and further steps, point is you should not paste anything, input form is for manual input, to pass values from external sources there is better ways designed to do it.